# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set' in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create and implement a simple form in Python using tkinter. The form itself was created using PAGE, I am now trying to write code to interact with the form (I'm still learning Python, so please bear with me).

I am getting an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set' when trying to dynamically set the text in a label from outside of the class where the label is defined. Everything I have read online indicates that this is the way to achieve my desired result, however I am stumped by this error. Any help is appreciated.

The error is occurring in the in the setTimerString function (which is part of the Pulse class).

Here is my main code file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.8.5
# In conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Feb 10, 2017 09:38:24 AM
import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1

import pulse_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root, top
    root = Tk()
    top = Pulse (root)
    pulse_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Pulse(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    top = Pulse (w)
    pulse_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Pulse():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

def startTimer():
    global count
    count = 0 # Reset it evert time the user starts the program
    top.setTimerString("12")


def runProgram():
    # Run the main program
    startTimer()

def closeProgram():
    exit()


class Pulse:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''

        self._bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        self._compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        self._ana2color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 

        top.geometry("320x344+599+249")
        top.title("Pulse")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        # Set the strings to use for the form
        self.countString = StringVar()
        self.timerString = StringVar()
        self.countString = "0"
        self.timerString = "0"

        self.btnExit = Button(top)
        self.btnExit.place(relx=0.84, rely=0.03, height=24, width=39)
        self.btnExit.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnExit.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.btnExit.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnExit.configure(command=closeProgram)
        self.btnExit.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.btnExit.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.btnExit.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnExit.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.btnExit.configure(pady="0")
        self.btnExit.configure(text='''Exit''')
        self.btnExit.configure(width=39)

        self.btnStart = Button(top)
        self.btnStart.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.17, height=104, width=125)
        self.btnStart.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnStart.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.btnStart.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnStart.configure(command=runProgram)
        self.btnStart.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.btnStart.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.btnStart.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.btnStart.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.btnStart.configure(pady="0")
        self.btnStart.configure(text='''Start''')
        self.btnStart.configure(width=125)

        self.Label1 = Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.31, rely=0.58, height=21, width=54)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Timer:''')
        self.Label1.configure(width=54)

        self.lblTimer = Label(top)
        self.lblTimer.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.58, height=21, width=32)
        self.lblTimer.configure(background="#a8aeff")
        self.lblTimer.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.lblTimer.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.lblTimer.configure(textvariable=self.countString)
        self.lblTimer.configure(width=32)

        self.Label3 = Label(top)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.67, height=21, width=43)
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''Count:''')

        self.lblCount = Label(top)
        self.lblCount.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.67, height=21, width=32)
        self.lblCount.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.lblCount.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.lblCount.configure(background="#ffa8a8")
        self.lblCount.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.lblCount.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.lblCount.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.lblCount.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.lblCount.configure(textvariable=self.countString)

        self.Label4 = Label(top)
        self.Label4.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.84, height=36, width=237)
        self.Label4.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label4.configure(text='''Press the start button to start the program.
Every time your pulse beats, press the P key.''')

    def setTimerString(self, newVal):
        self.timerString.set(newVal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: Read the error closely, and trust in what it is saying. It is telling you that an ordinary string does not have a `set` method. That is a true statement. So, either you are wrong about the method you want to call, or the variable isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.countString = StringVar()
self.countString = "0"
```

Will throw away the `StringVar` and replace it with a regular `str`, i.e. the kind that has no `set` method.

Instead

```
self.countString.set("0")
```

Comment: Great response, thanks for that. So simple now that I look at it.